# $(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha-1)(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha+1)=\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha+2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha-1$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm staring at it for hours and I can't make it up, can someone tell me why the bit before the = sign is the same as the bit after ?

$$(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha-1)(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha+1)=\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha+2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha-1$$

Comment: Have you tried actually distributing it on paper instead of just staring? (It would be even quicker if you have square-of-sum and difference-of-squares formulas memorized.)

Comment: Note that the right-hand-side can be reduced further to just $2 \sin \alpha \cos \alpha$.

Comment: To explain what @tylerc0816 is saying: $$ \sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha = 1. $$

Comment: Actually it can be reduced to sin(2a) ;)

Comment: @Mazzy True. I was just going to say. . .

Comment: Lesson to learn from this: Staring at an equation is not always a good way to understand it.

Comment: Got it now:)

$$(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha-1)(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha+1)=(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha)^2-1^2=\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha+2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha-1=1+\sin2\alpha -1=\sin2\alpha$$

Thanks everyone for the help, appreciate it!

Comment: @Mazzy No problem, thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses the Difference of Squares property which states that $$ (a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2.  $$In this case, let $a=\sin \alpha + \cos \alpha$ and $b=1$, and see what you get. I won't do the whole thing out for you since you haven't shown us an effort.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha$; then the lefthand side is $(u-1)(u+1)$, which is simply $u^2-1$. Now multiply out $u^2$, and you’ll see it.

Comment: 4 seconds this time! Upvote for you. Hope you'll return the favor. :)